# What is a well supported touchscreen driver to emulate?

Tags: drivers, hardware, touch-screen, hardware-compatibility

I'll spare the whys and hows of the project behind this but I am working on some hardware that needs to appear to the host Linux machine (Raspberry Pi) as a touchscreen*, ideally one that works over I2C or Serial bus and would be automatically discovered at boot time.

So the question is - what are some well supported I2C or Serial touchscreen devices that would be a good choice to emulate in the situation?

It ideally wants to be a well-supported & reliable driver so we don't have to do any tinkering with the host linux build to make it work, and simple enough that we don't have to jump through too many hoops on the emulation side either.

*= Or similar pointing device like a Wacom tablet I guess would work as it uses X/Y cooridinates rather than "mousey" movements.

Comment: You might want to explain a bit how the hardware would connect to the raspberry.

Comment: I did say "Ideally I2C or Serial" but have edited to make clearer.

Comment: From your comment to the current answer *"I am asking which devices tend to have mature existing drivers in most Linux builds"* How does **emulation** come into play? If it is just a hardware recommendation you are asking for, I'm afraid you are off-topic.

Comment: Eduardo - I am asking which device I should emulate with my hardware such that it is best supported by default in popular Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be much simpler to hook your device into [uinput](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/uinput.html) than emulate any kind of hardware touchscreen and its quirks.

Yes that will mean some kind of userland daemon that will translate between serial, etc and uinput, which will have to be installed as an extra, but even with plug-and-play serial mice (does anybody remember those?) it was still some userland driver that handled them: I don't that they were ever handled directly by the linux input subsystem.

Comment: You misunderstand - I am asking which devices tend to have mature existing drivers in most Linux builds (hence will plug-and-play) to save having to add drivers or other software/config to a standard Linux install.

Comment: @zevzek - The current GT9xx I2C touchscreen is discovered automatically on the I2C bus with no modifications, so what's that mechanism called?